# How to compare two Excel .xlsx files in PowerShell and output differences in another file

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell-5.0, file-compare

I have used the below code to compare the two files excel1 and excel2 and write the difference out to another file, but the output format is way different than expected.

```
Clear-Host

$File1 = Get-Content C:\Work\Compare\Excel1.xlsx
$File2 = Get-Content C:\Work\Compare\Excel2.xlsx

$Location = C:\Work\Compare\diff.csv

compare-object (get-content $File1) (get-content $File2) | format-list | Out-File $Location
```

**Excel1**
[image]

**Excel2**
[image]

**Output**
get-content : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Users\lchandrakanthredd\Desktop\Untitled2.ps1:8 char:38

- compare-object (get-content $File1) (get-content $File2) | format-lis

Appreciate your answers to the above question

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Get-Content reads texts from a file, or the bytes in a binary file into an array, how can it understand the content of xlsx files

Comment: What is the parameter used to get the data from Excel.?

Comment: there's none. You must have some library to parse the xlsx file